# Find restored files from recycle bin in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search, restore, recycle-bin

My aunt restored 2 deleted files from the recycle bin but she claimed she couldn't find them in the original location from which they were deleted. She couldn't quite recall the names of the files except that they were .pptx files. Is there an advanced search for something like this?

Comment: How many .pptx files do you have?

Comment: Nice question indeed..

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and none of the usual attributes change (I was specifically looking at Last Accessed Date), so I guess the answer is no. Your best bet is to search the drive for `*.pptx` files.

Comment: For fast file-name only searches, try [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

[AgentRansack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) can search the recycle bin. Search for `*.pptx` and it should find it if it's there.